# Maven parent pom: Unable to resolve imported document

Tags: java, maven, parent-pom

In the following project structure:

```
Parent
    - ProjectA
    - ProjectB
    - etc.
```

`ProjectA` build correctly when I run `mvn clean install` from within `ProjectA`.

However, when I run `mvn clean install` from the `Parent` folder I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.axis2:axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin:1.5.6:wsdl2code 
(default) on project ProjectA: Error parsing WSDL: 
WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document
at 'target/TcWebService.wsdl'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
This file was not found: 
file:/D:{PATH_TO_PARENT}/target/TcWebService.wsdl -> [Help 1]
```

**The correct path would be `file:/D:{PATH_TO_PARENT}/ProjectA/target/TcWebService.wsdl`. The `ProjectA` part is missing**

Parent.pom

```
<modules>
    <module>ProjectA</module>
    <module>ProjectB</module>
    ...
</modules>
```

ProjectA pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>{MY.GROUP.ID}</groupId>
    <artifactId>jars</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

...

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <copy file="src/main/wsdl/TcWebService.wsdl"
                          tofile="target/TcWebService.wsdl"/>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a more maven approach to this problem so that it is easier for maven to do what you ask of it.

The `maven-resources-plugin` will help you for sure.

Read up here : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

**EDIT**

I think the problem here is the working directory. when you run the child module, you are in the directory of the child project. so `childProject\target` works for you. However, when u run the main project, you are in the parent directory and this does not work. So this needs to be resolved by providing an absolute path to the file in both `file` and `tofile` of your copy task. `${project.basedir}` might help as a prefix to your paths.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful but the original problem remains the same.

Comment: the example shows which resource ou want to be copied in the target folder. Am I missing something?

Comment: use module dir to make the path to the file absolute

Comment: I'm not sure if you are musunderstanding something or if I am. The module builds perfectly well from within its own directory, but fails to build when run from the parent directory. Surely the parent doesn't need to copy resources from the child to the parent `target` directory just to build the child, when the child can build itself perfectly well?

I also could not find any information on `module dir`. Could you provide a link or example please? Thanks.